# validating podio web hook to gitlab

Tags: podio

I created a hook in Podio that calls a gitlab repository when a Podio item is changed. The repository then calls a pipeline that accesses the Podio API. The whole setup is working except that I am unable to verify the Podio hook: The Podio API requires some verification process (https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks) to be completed but I am unable to do this since I don't have control over how Gitlab deals with hooks. Is there a way to get my use case working?

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to call podio api, if you are unable to verify the hook do you get an error message back, then show the error message as well.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing it wrong but I am just clicking the 'verify' button on the Podio website. Should I be using API calls instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your webhook receiver code needs to respond with an API callback that is specific for the initial verification step.  In the API the "verify" is named as "validate"

https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/validate-hook-verificated-215241

https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks